# Diploma not yet received

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am writing my resume. I have finished college, but in my university there is an annoying (months long) wait after the last exam until people who have completed their work toward their degree receive their diploma. I am updating my resume and I would like a word to explain the situation.

Something like "degree in process" or "diploma pending". I feel this reads like I have not yet finished my studies, and that's not the case.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It depends on whether your student bus pass still works.

Comment: How about a phrase such as "all degree requirements fulfilled; awaiting diploma"? If you are trying to convey the nuances of a rather complicated situation, it makes sense to use as many words as it takes to represent the situation accurately.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a word for my situation, but I guess that's simply not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *graduand* refers to somebody who has passed all the exams for a degree but not yet *graduated* in the sense of receiving a certificate. It's not strictly accurate for a diploma, but I would think you could use it without causing too much confusion.

Comment: The word *graduand* is one that many people would take for a misspelling of *graduate* or some similar word.  Probably best avoided, at least in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks: the correct word is to be avoided because you think your audience won't understand it?  That sounds both patronizing and despairing.

Comment: If you look at the dictionary, it's a UK-only word.

Comment: I approved this answer, because it is exactly what I wanted in meaning. But I did not use it in my resume because it's apparently only used in the UK. Clarity is more important than terseness.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the need to be up front about not having the "piece of paper" yet you could say:  I obtained X degree in Y field on Month/Day/Year.  The certificate is presently being processed.

Am I correct in assuming it is the physical certificate you are awaiting?  Are you on record with the University as having graduated with your degree on a particular date, if someone were to contact the school?  If so, you may not need to mention it on the resume at all.

Comment: Well, in the unlikely case that there is some problem with the paperwork I wouldn't like for it to look like I lied on my resume. The record shows that I passed all my courses, and my thesis was approved, but I'm not sure it's correct to say I graduated until the ceremony and proccess is all done with.